# How to make a SwiftUI list scrollable in tvOS

Tags: listview, scroll, scrollview, swiftui, tvos

I have a `List` with content and when I build to an Apple Tv I cannot scroll to the bottom of the `List`.

I tried the focusable on the `List` rows but I cannot seem to get the list to scroll. I also replaced the `List` with a `ScrollView` to no avail.

```
List(self.someData) { data in
     SomeListRow(data: data)
}
.shadow(radius: 5)
.focusable(true)

List(self.someData) { data in
     SomeListRow(data: data)
      .focusable(true)

}
.shadow(radius: 5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SwiftUI on tvOS has a bug where if you set a shadow on something none of the components in it receive user input events such as focus.  There's an easy workaround though, just set your shadow on the background layer.

```
.background(
    Color.white
        .shadow(radius: 5)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I added the focusable in the `SomeListRow` and that didn't work but removing the `.shadow` on the `List` made it work. Must have been the order of the modifiers(still looking into it).